# How to find $ab+cd$ given that $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2=1$ and $ac+bd=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

It is given that $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2=1 $

And it is also given that $ac+bd=0$

What then is the value of $ab+cd$ ?

Comment: is the result $ab+cd=0$

Comment: Yes,  that is what I was told by the person who gave me this problem. How did you arrive at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution by Sumit Ray

$ac=-bd$

$\frac{a}{b} = -\frac{d}{c} = k$

$a=bk \text{ and }d=-ck$

$a^2+b^2=1\implies b^2 = \frac{1}{k^2+1}\implies c^2 = \frac{1}{k^2+1}$

Thus $b^2 - c^2 =0$

Now \begin{align*}ab+cd &= b^2\cdot k-c^2\cdot k\\&= k(b^2-c^2)
          = 0\end{align*}

Answer (score 27):

$$ab+cd=ab(c^2+d^2)+cd(a^2+b^2)=(ad+bc)(ac+bd)=0$$

Comment: no need for high level

Comment: But we need  (ab+cd ) as a factor and not (ad+bc)

Comment: @pirsquare. i don't understand your comment. On the far LHS we have $ab+cd$, equal to the far RHS, which is $0$.

Answer (score 10):

I assume $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $a^2+b^2 = 1$, we have $-1 \leq a \leq 1$ and likewise $-1 \leq b \leq 1$. Let us take $a = \cos(\alpha)$ and $b = \sin(\alpha)$ without loss of generality. Similarly, $c = \cos(\beta)$ and $d = \sin(\beta)$.

We have $ac + bd = \sin(\alpha) \sin(\beta) + \cos(\alpha) \cos(\beta) = \cos(\alpha - \beta) = 0$.

You have

$ab+cd = \cos(\alpha) \sin(\alpha) + \cos(\beta) \sin(\beta)\\
= \frac{1}{2} ( \sin(2 \alpha) + \sin(2 \beta) ) \\
= \sin(\alpha+\beta) \cos(\alpha - \beta) \\
= 0 $

The answer should be 0.

Comment: Is a algebraic solution possible?

Comment: I think so: by Hilbert's nullstellensatz over reals, we should have an algebraic argument. We could try to see if computer algebra system  like SAGE will do it like this: take the (radical) ideal generated by the polynomials $\{ a^2 + b^2 - 1, c^2 + d^2 -1, a c + bd \}$. See if $(ab + cd) $ belongs to it :-)

Comment: Many thanks! :-)

Comment: Or you could not assume $a$ and $b$ are real, forget about the bounds, and get exactly the same proof except that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are now also allowed to be complex...

Comment: SAGE code for ideal membership: a,b,c,d=QQ['a,b,c,d'].gens()
I=Ideal(1-a^2-b^2,1-c^2-d^2,a*c+b*d)
B=I.groebner_basis()
print(B)
p = a*b + c * d
q=p.reduce(B)
print(q) -- We obtain the output q = 0 !

Answer (score 5):

You can interptet $(a, b)$ and $(c, d)$ as two orthogonal vectors that lie on the unit circle. Converting this into polar coordinates, this means there are angles $\phi$, $\theta$ such that $(a, b) = (\cos(\phi), \sin(\phi))$, $(c, d) = (\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta))$ and $|\phi - \theta| = \frac{\pi}{2}$. Now observe that 
$$ab + cd = \cos(\phi)\sin(\phi) + \cos(\theta) \sin(\theta) = \sin(\phi + \theta)\cos(\phi - \theta) = 0$$
because $\cos\left(\pm \frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$ac+bd=0\iff\dfrac ad=\dfrac b{-c}=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{a^2+b^2}{d^2+(-c)^2}}$$

But if $a^2+b^2=d^2+c^2,$ not necessarily $=1$

$$\dfrac ad=\dfrac b{-c}=\pm1$$

So, either $a=d,b=-c$ or $a=-d,b=c$

The result should follow immediately.

Answer (score 1):

If $b=0,ac=0\implies c=0\implies ab+cd=0$

Else $ac+bd=0\iff ac=-bd\iff\dfrac ab=\dfrac{-d}c=k$(say)

$\implies a=bk, d=-ck$

If $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2,$ not necessarily $=1$

$b^2(1+k^2)=c^2(1+k^2)\implies b^2=c^2$ if $1+k^2\ne0$

Now $ab+cd=(bk)b+c(-ck)=k^2(b^2-c^2)=?$

Answer (score 0):

Now since $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2=1$ (a,b) and (c,d) are points on unit circle. You can think of these ordered pairs as vectors, since their dot product is zero. Then this means they are orthogonal. Now A x B gives area of triangle under first vector and C x D gives area under second vector. These triangles are similar since angles are all same, so we can use similarity principle (I'm not sure this is correct translation). Since hypothenuse's are same, meaning triangles are same, so their areas. But making 90 degree rotation means that in second vector x or y coordinate will change sign. So A x B = - C x D

https://i.hizliresim.com/nglMoN.jpg[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 0):

Let $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ be points on the unit circle. As shown in other comments, $ac+bd$ is generally $0$. But, when the point $(a,b)=(c,d)$ is on the axes, then the answer is $1$. 
$a=c=1, b=d=0$
$ac+bd=1$